# Get the value of HTML class, then put in in an input element

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

I've been trying to get the value of the ip address, which is already inside `<p id='details'></p>`to be put in the value of the input html class as well found on the last line.

I tried declaring it as a php variable but I couldn't afford so.

```
<script>
    var ipinfo;
    $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io", function (data) {
    $("#details").html(data.ip)
    })
</script>
    
<p id='details'></p>
    
<input type="text" name="ip" class="" value="@php echo ""; @endphp" readonly>
```

Comment: `$('input[name="value"]').value(data.ip)`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Oops, I meant `$('input[name="ip"]').value(data.ip)`

Comment: I've also tried this before, it doesn't work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i Can see you just need a token.

Also, I've used ES6 fetch method to get the API object response

```js
fetch('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=e0b12a7d02537a').then(
    (response) => response.json()
).then(
    (jsonResponse) => {
        //this will display the IP as a p elemenet text
        $('#details').html('IP Address = ' + jsonResponse.ip)
        //here we are assigning it as a value to the input
        $('input[name="ip"]').val(jsonResponse.ip);
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='details'></p>

<input type="text" name="ip" class="" readonly>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot a token could also help me solve the problem. It works the way I wanted to!

Comment: I'm glad I could help... All the best on your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly get hold of the content of a particular HTML class by copying over the value into a variable, and then inject this value by assigning the copied over variable's value into the input's value.
You could achieve this by using plain Vanilla JavaScript.

Since your `p` tag is initially empty and the data is injected into the `p` tag after it is fetched from a network, this process becomes an asynchronous task. So, you'd want to feed the data only after it is fetched, so you can add the value assigning logic within the fetch function as follows:

```
    var ipinfo;
    $.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io", function (data) {
      document.querySelector("#details").innerHTML = data.ip

      const inject = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")[0] //Identify the input element

      inject.value = data.ip //Assign the returned value to input's value.
    })
```

As you want the returned value from fetch to be fed to the `p` tag content as well as the input tag value, you could directly assign it, instead of copying over the already copied value.

Comment: Hello, I understand the logic behind this script, however the input's value still doesn't show the value. I've tried putting the script above, and below of the form but it still doesn't show.

Comment: Is the content present in the element when the page is initially loaded?

Comment: As per your code snippet, the `p` tag seems to be empty.

Comment: Yes, the content is present even though the p tag is empty as it fetch my ip address from the above code

Comment: Have you verified, if your fetch function is returning the correct data? I'm quite suspicious about the URL endpoint that you are using, I did try using the same URL and I'm unable to fetch any result

Comment: Yes it does, you might have some ad blocking features on your browser or some sort. I am using Brave Browser and it doesn't fetch the data I wanted to when I have my Brave shield on

Comment: You also have to add this I believe. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Got it. I've updated the code, kindly check.